# jquery: checking checkbox and unchecking only works once

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, razor

in my asp.net application (razor) a checkbox gets rendered which in the inspector lookslike this:

```
<input class="langCheck rowCounter0 evenRow" id="MainNodes_0__children_0__IsChecked" name="MainNodes[0].children[0].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked">
```

Now I wrote a button that is supposed to check ALL the checkboxes which the class "rowCounter0" attached to them.

```
 <button onclick="selectAll(@i)" class="buttonselectall" type="button">alle an/abwählen</button> 

function selectAll(idOfButton) {
    //todo BUG: only works once to check and once to uncheck - page needs refresh if done again and I DONT KNOW WHHHHHY

    var showOnce = true; 
    var className = '.rowCounter' + idOfButton  
    $(className).each(function () {


        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });

}
```

This button does work as it checks all the relevant checkboxes and when they are checked and the button is pressed again unchecks them all.
But if the button is pressed a third time (basically just to recheck), nothing is happening anymore and it drives my crazy.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Tested your snippet. It works fine all the time. Maybe something else is causing the problem. Maybe check the browser console?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did find a solution, maybe you can shed more light onto it why it works now?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by rewriting the jquery code

```
function selectAll(idOfButton) {
    var className = '.rowCounter' + idOfButton

    if ($(className).is(':checked')) {
        $(className).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $(className).prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

I cant really tell you why, but I guess I didnt use state of the art terminology.

Anyway, its fixed. Feel free to copy and paste my code.